# ¿como solucionar el error Warning: Cannot modify header information en php que sale desde una pagina subida a un servidor?

Tags: php, html, servidor

subi mi pagina web a 000wbhost, y me da el siguiente error:
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /storage/ssd3/368/19903368/public_html/index.php:10) in /storage/ssd3/368/19903368/public_html/contenidos/logout.php on line 6.

el error indica que esta en el archivo logout.php en la linea 6.
mi codigo logout.php solo tiene lo siguiente, ya elimine los espacios en blanco y  tampoco se soluciona:

```
<?php
//eliminar la sesion
session_unset();
//destruir la session
session_destroy();
header('Location: index.php?seccion=home');
?>
```

no se como puedo solucionar este error, alguna sugerencia por favor?

Answer (score 0):

Estas tratanto de destruir una sesion que acabas de iniciar (Ese es el error) y luego rediriges.  no tiene sentido

Si lo que intentas es  un script que cierre sesion

```
<?php
session_destroy();
header('Location: index.php?seccion=home');
 ?>
```